# Push Zip File created in Pipeline to ACR

Tags: maven, build, devops, pipeline, tap-harness

I Created a pipeline in Harness where I need to push the zip file which is created through Maven and that zip file needs to be uploaded to ACR through Shell Script.

I don't want to use Dockerfile or docker build since the build is already done through Maven.

Comment: What is a ACR?.